# opengl getUniformLocation

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

Im having trouble with getting a proper location of my uniform in my opengl shaders. I always but always get -1 returned from the glGetUniformLocation Function.

maybe I didnt load it well?

I read online that uniforms can get optimized out for not-using them, but I do use my uniforms in a way that can affect my shaders(or do I,I think I do).
also, everytime I encounter an answer that is related to this problem on stackoverflow or on some other site,they do talk about this fact, but NO ONE EXPLAINS about an alternative solution for this, and that realy got me struggling. is it something new just for new opengl iterations?

here is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 410 core                                                  

in vec4 position;                                                                                                                               
uniform mat4 mvmatrix;                                            
uniform mat4 projmatrix;                                          

void main(void)                                                    
{                                                                  
    gl_Position = projmatrix * mvmatrix * position;              
}
```

here is my fragment shader code:

```
#version 410 core                                                  

out vec4 color;                                                    



void main(void)                                                    
{                                                                  
    color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)                                  
}
```

and here is the whole source code for the whole program..for now I didnt implement the whole code itself,only the part that compliles the program and shaders, but yet, Im struggling to get the location for the uniforms, Ive been struggling with this for several days...hoping someone could save me here:

[codeHere](http://pastebin.com/LUHfMj98)

also if you need only the specific part that Im talking about:

```
//creating program and shaders, compiling shaders, compiling program
GLchar * v_Shader[] = {


    "#version 410 core                                                  \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "in vec4 position;                                                  \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "uniform mat4 mvmatrix;                                            \n"
    "uniform mat4 projmatrix;                                          \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "void main(void)                                                    \n"
    "{                                                                  \n"
    "    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;              \n"
    "}                                                                  \n"
};

GLchar * f_Shader[] = {
    "#version 410 core                                                  \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "out vec4 color;                                                    \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "in VS_OUT                                                          \n"
    "{                                                                  \n"
    "    vec4 color;                                                    \n"
    "} fs_in;                                                           \n"
    "                                                                   \n"
    "void main(void)                                                    \n"
    "{                                                                  \n"
    "    color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)                                  \n"
    "}                                                                  \n"
};

//creating a opengl program
program = glCreateProgram();

//creating the vertex shader and compiling it
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, v_Shader, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

//creating the fragment shader and compiling it
fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, f_Shader, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

//attaching the shaders to the program and linking the program
glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(program);
glUseProgram(program);
//getting the program's uniform locations
modelViewMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvmatrix");
projectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projmatrix");
```

And nope, I dont like using glfw/sdl/glew/freeglut or any other library. they just confuse me all around.

Comment: You need to see if compilation and link stages were successfull. If not, you can not use the program, which it will give you -1 always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misspelling the uniform names in the vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 mvmatrix;
uniform mat4 projmatrix;
...
gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;
```

To fix, replace `gl_Position` line with

```
gl_Position = projmatrix * mvmatrix * position;
```

To catch errors like this in the future, check the shader compile status:

```
GLint wasCompiled;
glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &wasCompiled );
GLint logLength;
glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength );
if (logLength > 0)
{
    GLchar* log = new GLchar[ (std::size_t)logLength + 1 ];
    GLsizei charsWritten = 0;            
    glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logLength, &charsWritten, log );
    std::cout << std::string( log );
}
```

You also have a syntax error in your fragment shader:

```
color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
```

It's missing `;` at the end. You should check for shader compile errors.

Your fragment shader takes color as input from vertex shader, but vertex shader doesn't output it and you don't use color input in the fragment shader. To fix, remove these lines:

```
"in VS_OUT                                                          \n"
"{                                                                  \n"
"    vec4 color;                                                    \n"
"} fs_in;                                                           \n"
```

In the latest version in the comments you have a line:

```
color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0.1.0)
```

There are 2 errors. You are missing `;` and the character before `1.0` should be `,`, not `.`

Comment: didnt help. still getting -1.

Comment: I accidentaly replaced names a while ago without noticing.you have no idea how much time I have been struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I did now try to compile it and you were right.altho I did what you suggested, it does seems to get GL_FALSE, so there is a problem with the shader,but everything seems ok.  I checked it zillion times.Ill try also printing the log and checking the problem

Comment: OK THE PROBLEM isnt the shaders even....glGetShaderIV doesnt even affect the value of the int...I set it to 2 and then used the function and it didnt effect the value of the int...maybe I loaded it wrong..sec

Comment: never mind...the shader is ok and isnt the problem..its something else.

Comment: ITS THE FRAGMENT SAHDER..............still dont know the problem tho...

Comment: @BinaryKiller Added one more tip at the end of the answer.

Comment: I noticed already but forgot to mention xD..here is the updated shader code:

Comment: I just cant seem to put my finger on the problem.and you can be sure that its with the fragment shader, because I re-checked everything, and the only one that doesnt compile is the fragment.trying atm to get the log and see the problem.

Comment: @BinaryKiller Your fragment shader is still missing `;` and contains extra `.`. The line should be: `color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`

Comment: OH GOD THANKS bro...when I started coding I was self-debugging myself in notepad++..but after a while I moved to visual studio..I think that with the time my auto-self-debugging skills went to the trash..and without visual studio debugging support, you never notice those begginner yet easy to not notice mistakes. AFTER Im finishing learning a bit more opengl, Ill move to linux and start coding with a notepad and some gcc full time xD

Comment: who thaught that even after 3 years of coding you can still make those mistakes.Ill give u ur vote bro, ur awesome, thanks :)

Comment: If you would query the GL_COMPILE_STATE and the GL_LINK_STATE (an their respective error logs), you would find such simple mistakes yourself...